Looking for Advice - PowerApps Form with multiple screens, creating and updating one singular record - Multiple Attachment fields
I have a SharePoint form customized with PowerApps in which a user navigates through multiple screens, filling out fields along the way, with an option to Save and return to the form at a later date.  I've figured out all the fields, except for the attachments.  I know SharePoint only allows one Attachments field per list, but my requirement is to have Attachments fields on multiple screens.  Basically the first screen contains the basic info (User's name, project, manager, etc.), including an Attachments field.  But the next two screens also have Attachments fields.  How can I tell the App to add whatever attachments are uploaded on those subsequent screens to that first screen's Attachments field, but then be able to return those values after submitting.  If a user populates that first screen, and includes an attachment, then Saves it - an item is created in SharePoint with all that data.  But when the user re-opens the form, navigates to the 2nd screen and adds an attachment there, then submits...I want this to update that existing record to now include both of those attachments.  And when the form is re-opened again, I want those attachments to display where they were entered.
Hope this makes sense.  It's ridiculous that SP only allows for one Attachments column per list, and that there's no clear cut way around that with PowerApps.  So any advice would be welcome.
Thank you!
